# CentOS 6.6 LDAP configuration failed

Tags: centos6, openldap

I'm trying to config OpenLDAP on CentOS 6.6 with this db.ldif config:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}UCCQrNoadIFC2lN0Y6YxzCfu9hT/jZni 
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}UCCQrNoadIFC2lN0Y6YxzCfu9hT/jZni 
-
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=genetics,dc=wustl,dc=edu
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=manager,dc=genetics,dc=wustl,dc=edu

dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to *  
 by dn.base=”gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth” read  by dn.base=”cn=manager,dc=genetics,dc=wustl,dc=edu” read  
 by * none
```

Than I run the command:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f db.ldif
```

But I get an error:

> modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config"
>   ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
>       additional info:  handler exited with 1

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled on this question with a similar problem myself.  I'd been trying to setup an LDAP server with selinux enabled and got a similar error.  If you have selinux enabled, try it in permissive mode or disable it and try again.

Not so good if you're trying for a secure system and ldap complains about selinux!